# EnsureLibraryPresent error in huysentruitw's SapNwRfc connector with .net5

Tags: c#, .net-5, sap-dotnet-connector

I'd like to use huysentruitw's [SapNwRfc](https://github.com/huysentruitw/SapNwRfc) connector to connect to SAP. I have copied all the necessary files to project root (sapnwrfc.dll, icuuc50.dll, icuin50.dll, icudt50.dll) but I still got error when I try to call this:

```
SapLibrary.EnsureLibraryPresent();
```

the error I got:

> System.BadImageFormatException
> HResult=0x8007000B
> Message=An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (0x8007000B)
> Source=SapNwRfcDotNet
> StackTrace:
> at SapNwRfc.Internal.Interop.RfcInterop.RfcGetVersion(UInt32& majorVersion, UInt32& minorVersion, UInt32& patchLevel)
> at SapNwRfc.Internal.Interop.RfcInterop.GetVersion(UInt32& majorVersion, UInt32& minorVersion, UInt32& patchLevel)
> at SapNwRfc.SapLibrary.GetVersion()
> at SapNwRfc.SapLibrary.EnsureLibraryPresent()

I have tried to changed platform from any CPU to x86 (then I got error from IIS Express), and x64 (the same behavior as any CPU)

Do you have any tips how to handle it?

Thank you.

EDIT

Tested with .NET Framework 4.7.2 and works fine. With Core 2.1, 3.1 and .NET5 does not work.

I have also tried it without copying the files into project folder and result is the same (files are present in `System32` and `SysWOW64` folders)

Comment: check this https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TensorFlowSharp/issues/222

Comment: I would say, open an issue in that github project, but I think you already did it (https://github.com/huysentruitw/SapNwRfc/issues/37).

Comment: Did you add sapnwrfc.dll in windows environment variables ?